# Не работают DTMF FreesWitch

Tags: asterisk, sip

При входящем звонке через транк, не работают DTMF, даже в консоли не отображаются. В Asterisk всё работало. Тип DTMF ставлю rf2833 как на Астере стоял.  На внутренних номерах всё работает. Кроме того если выполнить приложения start_dtmf а затем bridge, и дождаться пока вызываемый абонент возьмёт трубку DTMF начинают работать, даже если абонент сразу после ответа сбросит вызов.

В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Нашел ещё один костыль. Если после application answer выполнить любой playback application. DTMF тоже начинают работать как положено.

Comment: Нет, все-таки работают они с таким костылем через раз.

Answer (score 1):

Регистрация DTMF во FreeSWITCH возможно только после ответа на звонок. То етсь Вам необходимо дать команду `answer` в диалплане перед `start_dtmf`.

Практически, FreeSWITCH считает что из неотвеченного звонка он просто не может получить DTMF сигналы (не установлена медиа сессия)

Есть тонкий нюанс, связанный с тем, что теоретически в телефонной сети (SIP или нет - не важно) существует режим двусторонней передачи звука без ответа (для SIPа без отправки пакета с кодом 200 OK), но на практике я не встречал ни одного оператора, который бы это поддерживал, поэтому требование ответа во FreeSWITCH для регистрации DTMF вполне соответствует реалиям.